# How does the Ministry catch Illegal Magic around Muggles when performed by Adults?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory, laws

Harry's CoS letter from the *Improper Use of Magic Office* states

> We would also ask you to remember that any magical activity that risks notice by members of the non-magical community (Muggles) is a serious offense under section 13 of the International Confederation of Warlocks’ Statute of Secrecy.

We know that The Trace tracks magical activity around Underage Wizards, and hence can (theoretically) catch 'Improper Use of Magic' by wizards under 17 (though as we also see, it has a huge bunch of loopholes). We also learn in DH, that the Trace can not be placed on adults.

So how does the Ministry catch "serious offenses under section 13 of the International Confederation of Warlocks’ Statute of Secrecy" when the offender is an adult?

**ETA** (to clarify): This question is not about 'how does the Ministry track offenders in order to punish them' but about 'how does the Ministry track ***offenses*** (as mentioned in OP) in order to correct/clean up after them'.

Answer (score 3):

I think the Ministry would have a department that monitors the Muggle news, and it must have a way to track a magic spell performed in general. It figures out when some outrageous event happens and investigates and determines if it was done by a wizard affecting muggles or visible to them.

Cases in point being Harry and Ron get told off that their ride in Mr. Weasly’s flying car was seen in the ‘Chamber of Secrets’. Lucius Malfoy also tells Bill Weasley that his Flying car was photographed. Also when Cornelius Fudge discusses the situation with the Muggle Prime Minister with Voldemort killings highlighted in the newspaper.